# Check occurrence XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check occurrence of certain text. Below is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- Notify PANTONE - If YES -->
<xsl:if test="contains(xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute/PageColor,'PANTONE')">
<PantonePage><note>Yes</note></PantonePage>
</xsl:if>

<!-- Notify PANTONE - If NO -->
<xsl:if test="not(contains(xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute/PageColor,'PANTONE'))">
<PantonePage><note>No</note></PantonePage>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My desire output should be either:

```
<pantone>Yes</pantone>
```

or

```
<pantone>No</pantone>
```

In the original XML, PANTONE might be PANTONE Red U, PANTONE Green U. When tested the above XSLT, the answer is always NO.

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlreport>
  <PageInfo>
    <PageAttribute>
      <PageNum>1</PageNum>
      <TrimSize>
        <H>220 mm</H>
        <W>150 mm</W>
      </TrimSize>
      <MediaSize>
        <H>225 mm</H>
        <W>160 mm</W>
      </MediaSize>
      <PageColor>PANTONE Red U</PageColor>
    </PageAttribute>
    <PageAttribute>
      <PageNum>2</PageNum>
      <TrimSize>
        <H>220 mm</H>
        <W>150 mm</W>
      </TrimSize>
      <MediaSize>
        <H>225 mm</H>
        <W>160 mm</W>
      </MediaSize>
      <PageColor>Black</PageColor>
    </PageAttribute>
    <PageAttribute>
      <PageNum>3</PageNum>
      <TrimSize>
        <H>220 mm</H>
        <W>150 mm</W>
      </TrimSize>
      <MediaSize>
        <H>225 mm</H>
        <W>160 mm</W>
      </MediaSize>
      <PageColor>Cyan Magenta Yellow Black</PageColor>
    </PageAttribute>
  <PageInfo>
<xmlreport>
```

The `PageAttribute` will be repeated depending on number of pages.

Comment: Can you post your XML please for the relevant XPATH? It works for me with my assumed source XML, so maybe there is an attribute or something that I'm missing.

Comment: "*The PageAttribute will be repeated depending on number of pages.*" It's too bad your example doesn't reflect that - because that's the root of the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is that `contains()` is a *string* function and the  expression:

```
contains(xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute/PageColor,'PANTONE')"
```

tests only the string value of the **first** node of the set.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <PantonePage>
        <note>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute[contains(PageColor, 'PANTONE')]">Yes</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </note>
    </PantonePage>
</xsl:template>
```

Or - if you can accept a result of true/false instead of Yes/No - simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <PantonePage>
        <note>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean(xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute[contains(PageColor, 'PANTONE')])"/>
        </note>
    </PantonePage>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited stylesheet based on provided sample xml**

I changed the approach now knowing the business rules more clearly that you expect multiple page attributes within a page info element. Michael's answer definitely accounts for a single value being returns if any of the pages are pantone and is completely correct. The difference in the approach below is that is provides a structure to identify which of the pages are Pantone in case others who stumble on these answers are looking for that business rule by page.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </results>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xmlreport/PageInfo/PageAttribute">
        <Page>
            <PageNum><xsl:number/></PageNum>
            <Pantone>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(PageColor,'PANTONE')">Yes</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </Pantone>
        </Page>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Running this against your provided sample XML yields:**

```
<results>
    <Page>
        <PageNum>1</PageNum>
        <Pantone>Yes</Pantone>
    </Page>
    <Page>
        <PageNum>2</PageNum>
        <Pantone>No</Pantone>
    </Page>
    <Page>
        <PageNum>3</PageNum>
        <Pantone>No</Pantone>
    </Page>
</results>
```